# Update n elements having maximum values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to implement a soft delete in a mongo db collection (the hard delete is made once a day within a specific process).
My application can list all the active elements of the collection + the N most recent deleted elements.

My idea was to add a flag `to_delete` in my items: when deleting an element

- set the `deletion_date` to the current date
- set `to_delete: true` for the deleted elements except the 5 most recent (having highest `deleting_date`)

This way, my listing and hard delete are easy the implement:

- listing is a simple request returning all elements having `to_delete=false`
- hard delete is a simple request deleting all elements having `to_delete=true`

My question is to know I can write this query:

- set `to_delete: true` for the deleted elements except the 5 most recent (having highest `deleting_date`)

Comment: what happens if an update adds { age: 19 }? Won't it break your logic? I think setting `old: true` is a bad idea. Maybe keeping a stack `oldAges: [16, 18, 20]` would be easier.

Comment: The ages are never modified

Comment: well I still feel it's a bad pattern. What exactly is your need?

Comment: This was a simplified version of my problem. I've completely edited my post to explain something closer to my real use case

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need the `to_delete` field.

I would do a sort + limit to find the last N deleted:

```
const elements = await db.elements.find({ deletion_date: { $exists: true } }, { $sort: { deletion_date: -1 }, $limit: n });
```

If you add an index on `deletion_date`, the query is extremely fast. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#single-field.

And for the hard delete:

```
db.elements.remove({ 
    deletion_date: { $exists: true },
    _id: { $nin: elements.map(e => e._id) }
});
```

Comment: For the listing I need to find the last N deleted + the non deleted. And the hard delete the keep the N last deleted elements

Comment: `the last N deleted + the non deleted` well you simply use a $or.

Comment: It won't work since I use 'limit' to get the last N deleted. A limit on the "or" will break this. Or maybe I missed something?

Comment: @jaudo you are right, the $or doesn't work. You would indeed need two queries with that implem.